# Application of Hirzebruch Riemann Roch

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb C$ where $X$ is the universal cover of $Y$. Assume that the fundamental group of $Y$ is finite and has order $d$. Then we want to show that $\chi (X)=d \chi(Y)$ where $\chi(\cdot)$ means Euler characteristic with respect to the sheaf of regular functions.

Any ideas here? I guess it might be an easy application, but I don't see the connection between the chern class and the Todd class of $X$ and $Y$ in order to apply the Riemann Roch.

Comment: Crossposted from math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/326065/264

Comment: The question is purely topological, so HRR is not needed here. Just choose a triangulation of $Y$ and the induced triangulation of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it's not needed but I was reading "On the fundamental group of a unirational variety" by Serre, and he refers to HRR for this result; so I was wondering how HRR (or even GRR) implies the above.

Comment: The characteristic classes are of the tangent bundles, and the tangent bundle pulls back to the tangent bundle, along etale maps.

Comment: @Sasha : the question seems to be about the "holomorphic" Euler characteristic (Euler characteristic of the sheaf of regular functions) and not the topological Euler characteristic.


Comment: Let $\pi:X\to Y$ be the given morphism. You may compute that $\chi(X,{\cal O}_X)=\chi(Y,\pi_*({\cal O}_X))$. Now using either the fact that $\pi_*({\cal O}_X)$ is flat as a $C^\infty$-bundle or Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch together with Allen Knutson's remark, you conclude that ${\rm ch}(\pi_*({\cal O}_X))=d={\rm deg}(\pi)$. Now applying Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch, you get that 
$\chi(Y,\pi_*({\cal O}_X))=\int_Y{\rm ch}(\pi_*({\cal O}_X)){\rm Td}(X)=d\cdot \int_Y{\rm Td}(X)=d\chi(X,{\cal O}_X)$.

Comment: $\chi(\mathcal{O}_X) = \int_X \mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{O}_X) \mathrm{Td}(T_X) = \int_X \mathrm{ch}(f^* \mathcal{O}_Y) \mathrm{Td}(f^* T_Y) = d \int_Y \mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{O}_Y) \mathrm{Td}(T_Y) = d \chi(\mathcal{O}_Y)$.  Here, the first and last equality are HRR, the third is push-pull, and the second is Allen's remark (which is better decompressed by pulling back than by pushing forward). 